# Java Script - Identifying specific strings and pushing them into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push my name into the hits array once its identified in the text list. For some reason its not pushing into the hits array. How can I get my name into the hits array? What do you see that I don't? Thanks

```
var text = ("Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah")

var myName = "Stan"

var hits = []

for (i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === "S") {
        for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, text is not an array. It will hold the string `Blah` for a single time

Comment: As you can see in your `hits` variables, arrays are declared with `[]`, not `()`

Answer (score 0):

`var text = ("Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah")` is surrounded by parentheses.

You need to iterate over an array, whose literals are declared with brackets.

`var text = ["Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah"]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = ["Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah", "Stan", "Blah", "Blah", "Blah"]

var myName = "Stan"

var hits = []

for (i = 0; i <= (text.length-1); i++) {
   if(text[i].indexOf('S') > -1){
     hits.push(text[i]);
   }
     
}
```